# Creating a text area that accepts html as input in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, formtastic

I am new to rails.I want to create a text area that will accepts html as input and can process them as well.
I dont know how to do this .I am using formtastic gem for my form.

Please help me out.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type any valid html on your text area, save, and then show the string with html_safe method, it should parse the html as usual.

Example: `"<b>Hello bold</b>".html_safe` should render **Hello bold** on the screen.